# Manually set the ID's of form input fields in a simpleform form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, simple-form

Is it possible to overrule simpleform's naming of textfields within a form?

This:

```
= f.input_field :age_from,
```

Outputs in:

```
<input type="text" size="50" name="/people/search[query]" id="_people_search_query">
```

Should be

```
<input type="text" size="50" name="/people/search[query]" id="query">
```

I tried
* :name => "query"
* :id => "query"

to no avail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like your other question html options should be passed in input_html hash in simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :age_from, ..., :input_html => { :id => 'my_id' } %> should work.
```

Comment: works but for some strange reason a certain input diden't worked due to the order of properties

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass it in the html attribute hash

html: {id: 'query'}

Comment: thx for the suggestion tried but diden't worked. Cannot find any documentation on how to set an id value in simpleform neither :(