# Access form_group div via id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to perform a check to provide instant validation feedback on the input of a field in my bootstrap form for my Profiles model using java/coffee-script. My current solution is working but feels rather clunky and I would like to improve it.

Here are some code examples of what I'm doing.

app/views/profiles/_form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@profile, layout: :horizontal, html: {id: "profile-form"} ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :number, id: "number-field" %> //Field to check
    <%= form_group do %>
        <%= f.primary %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

app/assets/javascript/profile_number_control.coffee:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  $field = $("#number-field")
  $group = document.getElementById("profile-form").childNodes[5]
  numberPattern = "^(19|20)[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}$"
  $helpBlock = $group.getElementsByClassName("help-block")[0]

  $field.keyup ->
    //This works fine, just wanted to show what is going on
    if inputIsValid()
      set $group class to " has-success"         
      set $helpBlock message to successful
    else 
      set $group class to " has-error"
      set $helpBlock message to corresponding error message
```

Here is the problem. I want this script to work for both profile#new and profile#edit, but since the array of elements given by `document.getElementById("profile-form").childNodes` differs in length depending of the current view I can not use the same index (5 in the example) for both #new and #update.

Does anyone know how to set an id to that specific form_group in my view? Or do I have to actually write out the whole html code to be able to place an id there properly?

Comment: Check this out, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202142/manually-set-the-ids-of-form-input-fields-in-a-simpleform-form

Comment: Found a solution by using a wrapper according to the [docs](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms). This doesn't allow adding of an id but you may add a class. So I did a workaround with a uniquely named class instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might help !

```js
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@profile, layout: :horizontal, html: {id: "profile-form"} ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :number, :input_html => { id: "number-field" } %> //Field to check
    <%= form_group do %>
        <%= f.primary %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Probably would have worked if I used simple_form which I don't. I will keep trying and maybe switch if I dont find another solution. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Well if you are using Rails 4 why do you use bootstrap form ? Why dont you use what Rails give you on the first place ?

Comment: I'm actually using a nested_bootstrap_form and by "give you on the first place?" do you mean while scaffolding? Because if so I prefer to write my own code, scaffolding tends to bloat the code a bit.